# On pushing object I am getting everything as NULL angular2+typescript

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, angular2-forms

I have bind shift to a html form on submit I want to push object to a `array.JSON.stringify(shift1)` gives me correct result.

But when I push it in array. Everything becomes pushed as NULL.

I am not getting whats happening. I have used interface.

Is it making any type casting problems? Its annoying.

How to handle interfaces in typescript? Thats also a riddle to me.

On Every add `shift1` gets same object `this.shift`. How to create a new object assign updated to new `Interface` then pushing it to `Array`?

```
              import {
              Component,
              OnInit,
              AfterViewInit
          } from '@angular/core';
          import {
              ScriptService
          } from './services/script.service';
          import {
              DatePipe
          } from '@angular/common';



          interface shiftDetails {

              shift_name ? : string;
              shift_type ? : string;
              base_working_hour ? : string;
              start_time ? : string;
              end_time ? : string;
              multiple_check_in_check_out ? : boolean;
              consider_breaks ? : boolean;
              break_time ? : string;
              pre_shift_time ? : string;
              post_shift_time ? : string;

          }
          @Component({

              templateUrl: 'org-setup.component.html',
          })

          /*class OUUnits {
            isChecked = false;
            name: string;

          }*/



          export class OrgSetupComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {




              shift: shiftDetails = {
                  shift_name: null,
                  shift_type: null,
                  base_working_hour: null,
                  start_time: null,
                  end_time: null,
                  multiple_check_in_check_out: false,
                  consider_breaks: false,
                  break_time: null,
                  pre_shift_time: null,
                  post_shift_time: null
              };
              ShiftDetails1: shiftDetails[] = [];


              Sdate: string;
              Edate: string;
              customCal: string;
              constructor(private script: ScriptService, private datePipe: DatePipe) {}

              ngOnInit() {



                  //  this.shift.base_working_hour=null;


              }

              ngAfterViewInit() {
                  this.script.loadScript("/assets/script.js");
                  this.script.loadScript("/assets/app/js/plugins/forms/repeater/jquery.repeater.min.js");
                  this.script.loadScript("/assets/app/js/components/forms/form-repeater.js");
                  // this.script.loadScript("/assets/app/js/plugins/forms/toggle/bootstrap-switch.min.js");
                  this.script.loadScript("/assets/app/js/components/forms/switch.js");
                  console.log("Scrip afterview Init");
              }



              get bmds() {
                  return JSON.stringify(this.BiometricDevices);
              }

              addShift() {
                  console.log("adding shidt");
                  let shift1: shiftDetails = {};
                  //shift1 = shift;
                  shift1 = this.shift;
                  console.log(JSON.stringify(shift1));
                  this.ShiftDetails1.push(shift1);
                  //  console.log(JSON.stringify(this.ShiftDetails1));

              }

              get shifts() {
                  return JSON.stringify(this.ShiftDetails1);
              }




          }
```

Here is html code

```
        <div class="col-sm-12 mt-1">
       <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addshift" class="btn btn-secondary primary-blue">
       + Add shift
       </a>
       {{ shifts }}
    </div>
    <div class="modal fade" id="addshift" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
       <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
             <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">
                   Setup a new shift
                   <br>
                   <span class="small text-muted font-small-2">Enter your time-out to submit your request</span>
                </h5>
             </div>
             <form (ngSubmit)="addShift() ; shiftForm.reset()" #shiftForm="ngForm">
             <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="row">
                   <div class="col-sm-6">
                      <label>Shift name </label>
                      <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="shift.shift_name" name="shift_name" placeholder="Shift name" class="form-control" #shift_name="ngModel" >
                   </div>
                   <div class="col-sm-6">
                      <label for="">Allow multiple punch-in punch-out? <i class="icon-help-circled primary-blue font-medium-1"></i></label>
                      <div class="form-group position-relative">
                         <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="shift.multiple_check_in_check_out" name="multiple_check_in_check_out" #multiple_check_in_check_out="ngModel" class="switchBootstrap" id="switchBootstrap8" data-on-text="Yes" data-off-text="No" data-on-color="success" />
                      </div>
                   </div>
                </div>
                <label>Shift type </label>
                <div class="form-group position-relative">
                   <label class="display-inline-block custom-control custom-radio">
                   <input type="radio" name="inlineRadio1" [(ngModel)]="shift.shift_type" value="1" name="shift_type" #shift_type="ngModel" class="custom-control-input"> <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span> <span class="custom-control-description font-size-1">Start time-End time</span>
                   </label>
                   <label class="display-inline-block custom-control custom-radio">
                   <input type="radio" name="inlineRadio1" [(ngModel)]="shift.shift_type" value="2" name="shift_type" #shift_type="ngModel" checked="true" class="custom-control-input"> <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span> <span class="custom-control-description">Working hours</span>
                   </label>
                   <input type="text" placeholder="Base working hours" [(ngModel)]="shift.base_working_hour" name="base_working_hour" class="form-control" #base_working_hour="ngModel">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group position-relative">
                   <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-sm-6">
                         <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="shift.start_time" name="start_time" placeholder="Start time" class="form-control" #start_time="ngModel">
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-sm-6">
                         <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="shift.end_time" name="end_time" #end_time="ngModel" placeholder="End time" class="form-control">
                      </div>
                   </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                   <div class="col-sm-6">
                      <label for="">Consider breaks in calculation?</label>
                      <div class="form-group position-relative">
                         <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="shift.consider_breaks" name="consider_breaks" #consider_breaks="ngModel" class="switchBootstrap" id="switchBootstrap8" data-on-text="Yes" data-off-text="No" data-on-color="success" />
                      </div>
                   </div>
                   <div class="col-sm-6">
                      <label>Break duration</label>
                      <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="shift.break_time" name="break_time" #break_time="ngModel" placeholder="Please enter break duration" class="form-control">
                   </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group position-relative">
                   <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-sm-6">
                         <label>Pre-shift Time </label>
                         <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="shift.pre_shift_time" name="pre_shift_time" #pre_shift_time="ngModel" placeholder="Earliest allowed start time" class="form-control">
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-sm-6">
                         <label>Post-shift Time </label>
                         <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="shift.post_shift_time" name="post_shift_time" #post_shift_time="ngModel" placeholder="Latest allowed end time" class="form-control">
                      </div>
                   </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group position-relative"> </div>
             </div>
             <div class="modal-footer">
                <input type="reset" class="btn btn-secondary primary-blue" data-dismiss="modal" value="Close">
                <input type="submit"   [disabled]="!shiftForm.form.valid" class="btn btn-info bg-blue bg-darken-2 no-border" value="Add">
             </div>
             </form>
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You aren't assigning any values to it, so I'd expect it to be null, right? :)

Comment: Its binded to form. No need to assign value explicitly

Comment: right, I missed the fact that you were using two-way-binding in your form :P But I think I found the issue, would just need to debug the code to make sure.

Comment: Appreciate your effort.. Typescript is bit confusing when it comes to type casting. Its better not to define type of the object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this behavior, is because you are using two-way-binding. When you use `reset` in your form, your `shift` gets the initial values, which all are `null`. So when the form is reset at the same time as you are submitting form, and you are veeeery shortly thereafter pushing values to your array. This means you are actually pushing the already reset values, which are all `null`.

This can be solved by not using two-way-binding, but instead pushing the object that is created by the form to the array. So remove `[(ngModel)]` and use just `ngModel` instead. You have built the form as such, that the object that is created by the form, matches the model, so in your submit, you can reference the parameter of being of type `shiftDetails`:

```
addShift(value: shiftDetails) { // here
  this.ShiftDetails1.push(value);
}
```

and your template (shortened version) should look like this: (Remember to pass the form value in your submit):

```
<form (ngSubmit)="addShift(shiftForm.value) ; shiftForm.reset()"  #shiftForm="ngForm">
   <label>Shift name </label>
   <input type="text"  name="shift_name" placeholder="Shift name" class="form-control" ngModel #shift_name="ngModel" >
   <label>Shift type </label>
   <label class="display-inline-block custom-control custom-radio">
     <input type="radio" name="inlineRadio1" ngModel value="1" name="shift_type" #shift_type="ngModel" class="custom-control-input">
   </label>
   <label class="display-inline-block custom-control custom-radio">
      <input type="radio" name="inlineRadio1" ngModel value="2" name="shift_type" #shift_type="ngModel" checked="true" class="custom-control-input">
    </label>
    <input type="submit"   [disabled]="!shiftForm.form.valid" class="btn btn-info bg-blue bg-darken-2 no-border" value="Add">
</form>
```

### [DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/aObH7b28elapHk6xdr3T?p=preview)

Comment: I have figured it out lately. However your answer has helped me to learn how to use **Form.value** . Thanks

Comment: My question would be... how do you decouple the object that you push so that you CAN reset it and keep using two way binding.  I have extra fields in the ngModel that I want to push.